# Dual boot Win10/Pop_OS - /vmlinuz.efi has invalid signature

Tags: linux

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHUqM.jpg)

I mounted the pop_os in 2 different pen drives (8gb and 4gb), I had the same error both times.
The file isn't corrupted because I using a Virtual Machine created with the same file.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can probably ask on [unix.se] instead, but first please take [their tour](//unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [I realize this question is old; I'm just saying the same thing I would for a new question, and just in case any beginners end up here.]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solved it by disabling secure boot in the BIOS (Only signed kernel works with the secure boot enabled).

You can sign the kernel by following some tutorials on youtube (I didn't do that).